# JPA using multiple database schemas

Tags: java, database, spring, jpa, schema

I'm having a bit of trouble with one particular issue using JPA/Spring:

How can I dynamically assign a schema to an entity?

We have TABLE1 that belongs to schema AD and TABLE2 that is under BD.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE1", schema="S1D")
...

@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE2", schema="S2D")
...
```

The schemas may not be hardcoded in an annotation attribute as it depends on the environment (Dev/Acc/Prd).  (In acceptance the schemas are S1A and S2A)

How can I achieve this?  Is it possible to specify some kind of placeholders like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE1", schema="${schema1}")
...

@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE2", schema="${schema2}")
...
```

so that schemas are replaced based on a property file residing in the environment?

Cheers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem I solved that with a persistence.xml in which I refer to the needed orm.xml files within I declared the db shema

```
<persistence
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0" >
<persistence-unit name="schemaOne">
    . . .
    <mapping-file>ormOne.xml</mapping-file>
    . . .
</persistence-unit>

<persistence-unit name="schemaTwo">
    . . .
    <mapping-file>ormTwo.xml</mapping-file>
    . . .
 </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

now you can create a EntityManagerFactory for your special schema

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("schemaOne");
```

Comment: what about if there is a relation between ormOne and OrmTwo ?

Answer (score 3):

One thing you can do if you know at deployment is to have 2 orm.xml files. One for schema1 and one for schema2 and then in the persistence.xml you have 2 persistence-units defined. Putting annotations is an anti-pattern if needing to change things like schema

Answer (score 3):

I posted this on github but also cross posting it here.

I found you can accomplish a dynamic schema configuration for multiple schemas in different environments by overriding the physical naming strategy.

Let's say you have two entities like this which are configured for two different schemas -

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="TABLE1", schema="schema1")
public class FooEntity implements Serializable {
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="TABLE2", schema="schema2")
public class BarEntity implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```

First create a configuration in your application.yml file:

```yaml
multischema:
  config:
    schema1: FIRSTSCHEMA
    schema2: SECONDSCHEMA
```

Bind it to a ConfigurationProperties bean

```java
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("multischema")
public class MultiSchemaConfigurationProperties {

    private Map<String,String> config;

    public void setConfig(Map<String,String> config) {
        this.config = config;
    }

    public Map<String,String> getConfig() {
        return config;
    }

}
```

Create a custom physical naming strategy which injects MultiSchemaConfigurationProperties and extends the Spring Boot default for your version.  In this case I'm using Spring Boot 2.6.4 which uses CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy.

```java
@Component
public class MultiSchemaPhysicalNamingStrategy extends CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy {

    private final MultiSchemaConfigurationProperties schemaConfiguration;

    public MultiSchemaPhysicalNamingStrategy(MultiSchemaConfigurationProperties schemaConfiguration) {
        this.schemaConfiguration = schemaConfiguration;
    }

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalSchemaName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnvironment) {
        if(name != null) {
            Identifier identifier = super.getIdentifier(schemaConfiguration.getConfig()
                    .get(name.getText()), name.isQuoted(), jdbcEnvironment);
            return super.toPhysicalSchemaName(identifier, jdbcEnvironment);
        }
        return name;
    }

}
```

When the application starts up Hibernate will invoke the custom physical naming strategy to apply the physical naming rule for your schema using the provided configuration in application.yml.  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-access.configure-hibernate-naming-strategy

"schema1" in FooEntity will be replaced by the value "firstschema" and "schema2" in BarEntity will be replaced by the value "secondschema".

Comment: Has anyone tried this solution? Does it work all the way?

Comment: We haven't run into any issues using this approach.  At first we tried to create multiple datasources but that would mean separate transaction managers, one per schema.  Once you have separate transaction managers you will run into other issues where you can't use multiple schemas within the same transaction.  This way we are still using one datasource/transaction manager and have a dynamic configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Try following:

```
puplic class MyClass {
  public static final String S1D="S1D";
  public static final String S2D="S2D";
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE1", schema=MyClass.S1D)
...

@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE2", schema=MyClass.S2D)
...
```

Comment: May I know how this solution will work for different environments as the schema name changes in each env?

Answer (score 1):

You could have two DataSource declarations (one for each schema) in your context.xml and define two persistence units using this datasources. The context.xml can then be different on the appservers of the different environments.

Answer (score 1):

when you create a datasource, you may be able to initialize the connection to use different schema

e.g. for weblogic

[Specify default schema for JDBC pool in weblogic/oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16065230/specify-default-schema-for-jdbc-pool-in-weblogic-oracle)

Answer (score 0):

Annotation arguments have to be final and can therefore not be changed at runtime.