# Specify default schema for JDBC pool in weblogic/oracle

Tags: oracle, jdbc, weblogic

We use the same user for multiple projects and I want to have a different default schema for different connection pools. 
Is there a way to specify the default schema in the weblogic JDBC configuration?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out myself:

If you go to **Data Source**-> **Configuration** -> **Connection Pool** -> click **Advanced**,

There is `Init SQL` there that will be executed for initialization of newly created physical db connection, we can put:

`SQL ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=animals`

to make the default schema.

Comment: Note: The `SQL ` is mandatory! (Check "Init SQL" at https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/FMWCH/pagehelp/Corecorepartitionservicesappjdbcmoduleconfigconnectionpooltitle.html)