# Multiple data store in one application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

In my project I'm using spring framework 3, jpa 2 (provider hibernate). I want to design my project such a way that my database schema is replicated on different database instances with same schema. And at the run time I want to switch over the schema for data operations.

So it means that one instance of my business logic and multiple instance of database. So it is possible? [image: This image shows the rough scratch of the typical structure, I wish to use in my project]

Edit: No of schemas are not predefined it will be decided on the fly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JPA using multiple database schemas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301399/jpa-using-multiple-database-schemas)

Comment: Yes, I've already visited this link. Sorry I forget to mention that no of schema is not predefined it will be decided on the fly. In the link they have defined schemas in persistence.xml