# JPA Stored procedure dynamic schema

Tags: jpa, stored-procedures, dynamic-schema

I'm using JPA 2.1 eclipselink to call Stored Procedures from the database and i don't want to hardcoded the schema name. Is there a way to switch between schemas dynamically?

I'm using JPA 2.1, EclispseLink 2.5.2, weblogic 12.1.3

EDITED: Schema name is unknown, so i cannot create mapping file for each schema. Plus I might have 5-10 schemas in the database. What I want is a way to go to the database, select a schema name and switch them at runtime

Comment: possible duplicate of [JPA using multiple database schemas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301399/jpa-using-multiple-database-schemas)

Comment: @lad2025 does not solve my problem