# JPA: many to one mapping from table in another database

Tags: java, jpa

I have an existing table (let's call this Tickets), and I need to have a many-to-one relationship into a table in another database (let's call this Transaction). I know that it's impossible to have a many-to-one relationship in JPA, but what I am looking for is to connect these two tables without resorting to JPA. Also, merging these tables to one db is not an option (as per client request).

I'm at a loss here.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Can you show us some code about what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on this answer ([JPA using multiple database schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301399/jpa-using-multiple-database-schemas)) I think that you would need to do something like:

```
public class Schemas {
  public static final String S1D="S1D";
  public static final String S2D="S2D";
}

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "Tickets", schema=Schemas.S1D)
public class Tickets {

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "transaction_id")
    private Transaction transaction;

}

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "Transaction", schema=Schemas.S2D)
public class Transaction {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not impossible to have a ManyToOne relationship in JPA. Here you have an example:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToOne

Concerning how to solve your particular problem using tables in two databases, you could use two different data sources, or a view on one of the databases, pointing to the table on the other one. The choice mainly depends on the nature of the databases you're trying to connect.

Comment: What particular technology would you use for a cross-database view? Considering there's no knowledge of actual databases being used.

Comment: It depends on the databases being used, but it's not an unusual solution.

Comment: And particularly easy to implement, if e.g. you're using two different instances of Oracle.

Comment: True, if you're using the same databases. If you don't require referential integrity. It's not a *great* solution.

Comment: Well...the question doesn't give much info, so I opened the spectrum of solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of implementing a many-to-many parent-child relationship using JPA, with a Category table and a mapping table, as well as a save API and a fetch API by root ID:

Here is an example of implementing a many-to-many parent-child relationship using JPA, with a Category table and a mapping table, as well as a save API and a fetch API by root ID:

```
@Entity

public class Category {

  @Id

  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

  private Long id;



  private String name;



  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)

  @JoinTable(

      name = "category_mapping",

      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id"),

      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "child_id")

  )

  private Set<Category> children;



  // getters and setters

}


@Entity

public class CategoryMapping {

  @Id

  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

  private Long id;



  @ManyToOne

  @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")

  private Category category;



  @ManyToOne

  @JoinColumn(name = "child_id")

  private Category child;



  // getters and setters
}
```

[check here][1]

https://java-speed.blogspot.com/2023/02/jpa-implemntation-many-to-many-parent.html