# Corda persiste state using configuration file

Tags: corda

I use below code to store IOU object to database.

```
return when (schema) {
    is IOUSchemaV1 -> IOUSchemaV1.PersistentIOU(
        this.lender.name.toString(),
        this.borrower.name.toString(),
        this.value,
        this.externalRef,
        this.linearId.id
)
```

I would like to know if it is possible to define the persistence logic in the configuration file (similar to [JPA using multiple database schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301399/jpa-using-multiple-database-schemas)) so that I it easy to define persistence logic for multiple objects/tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed possible to define persistence logic inside a CorDapp. The state you wish to persist should implement the Queryable State interface which will require two methods: supportedSchemas() and generateMappedObject().

The supportedSchemas methods will determine which Schema classes should be passed to the generateMappedObject method. The generateMappedObject method (which you have included a snippet from) will then create a representation of the data to persist.

```html
   @Override
    public Iterable<MappedSchema> supportedSchemas() {
        return ImmutableList.of(new TokenSchemaV1());
    }
```

```html
    @Override
    public PersistentState generateMappedObject(MappedSchema schema) {
        if (schema instanceof TokenSchemaV1) {
            return new TokenSchemaV1.PersistentToken(
                    this.getOwner().getName().toString(),
                    this.getIssuer().getName().toString(),
                    this.getAmount(),
                    this.linearId.getId(),
                    this.getListOfPersistentChildTokens()
            );
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unrecognised schema $schema");
        }
    }
```

The representation generated from the generateMappedObject method is passed to the ORM and persisted to the database as specified by JPA annotations in the Schema. See the code snippet below for an example schema class in Java. The snippet also demonstrates how one might make multiple tables for collections and sub-collections.

```html
/**
 * An IOUState schema.
 */

@CordaSerializable
public class TokenSchemaV1 extends MappedSchema {

    public TokenSchemaV1() {
        super(TokenSchema.class, 1, ImmutableList.of(PersistentToken.class, PersistentChildToken.class, PersistentGrandChildToken.class));
    }

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "token_states")
    public static class PersistentToken extends PersistentState {
        @Column(name = "owner") private final String owner;
        @Column(name = "issuer") private final String issuer;
        @Column(name = "amount") private final int amount;
        @Column(name = "linear_id") public final UUID linearId;
        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
        @JoinColumns({
                @JoinColumn(name = "output_index", referencedColumnName = "output_index"),
                @JoinColumn(name = "transaction_id", referencedColumnName = "transaction_id"),
        })
        private final List<PersistentChildToken> listOfPersistentChildTokens;

        public PersistentToken(String owner, String issuer, int amount, UUID linearId, List<PersistentChildToken> listOfPersistentChildTokens) {
            this.owner = owner;
            this.issuer = issuer;
            this.amount = amount;
            this.linearId = linearId;
            this.listOfPersistentChildTokens = listOfPersistentChildTokens;
        }

        // Default constructor required by hibernate.
        public PersistentToken() {
            this.owner = "";
            this.issuer = "";
            this.amount = 0;
            this.linearId = UUID.randomUUID();
            this.listOfPersistentChildTokens = null;
        }

        public String getOwner() {
            return owner;
        }

        public String getIssuer() {
            return issuer;
        }

        public int getAmount() {
            return amount;
        }

        public UUID getLinearId() {
            return linearId;
        }

        public List<PersistentChildToken> getChildTokens() { return listOfPersistentChildTokens; }
    }

    @Entity
    @CordaSerializable
    @Table(name = "token_child_states")
    public static class PersistentChildToken {
        @Id
        private final UUID Id;
        @Column(name = "owner")
        private final String owner;
        @Column(name = "issuer")
        private final String issuer;
        @Column(name = "amount")
        private final int amount;
        @Column(name = "child_proof")
        private final String childProof;
        @ManyToOne(targetEntity = PersistentToken.class)
        private final TokenState persistentToken;
        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
        @JoinColumn(name = "parent_linear_id", referencedColumnName = "Id")
        private final List<PersistentGrandChildToken> listOfPersistentGrandChildTokens;


        public PersistentChildToken(String owner, String issuer, int amount, List<PersistentGrandChildToken> listOfPersistentGrandChildTokens) {
            this.Id = UUID.randomUUID();
            this.owner = owner;
            this.issuer = issuer;
            this.amount = amount;
            this.persistentToken = null;
            this.childProof = "I am a child";
            this.listOfPersistentGrandChildTokens = listOfPersistentGrandChildTokens;
        }

        // Default constructor required by hibernate.
        public PersistentChildToken() {
            this.Id = UUID.randomUUID();
            this.owner = "";
            this.issuer = "";
            this.amount = 0;
            this.persistentToken = null;
            this.childProof = "I am a child";
            this.listOfPersistentGrandChildTokens = null;
        }

        public UUID getId() {
            return Id;
        }

        public String getOwner() {
            return owner;
        }

        public String getIssuer() {
            return issuer;
        }

        public int getAmount() {
            return amount;
        }

        public TokenState getPersistentToken() {
            return persistentToken;
        }



    }

    @Entity
    @CordaSerializable
    @Table(name = "token_grand_child_states")
    public static class PersistentGrandChildToken {
        @Id
        private final UUID Id;
        @Column(name = "owner")
        private final String owner;
        @Column(name = "issuer")
        private final String issuer;
        @Column(name = "amount")
        private final int amount;
        @Column(name = "child_proof")
        private final String childProof;
        @ManyToOne(targetEntity = PersistentChildToken.class)
        private final TokenSchemaV1.PersistentChildToken persistentChildToken;

        public PersistentGrandChildToken(String owner, String issuer, int amount) {
            this.Id = UUID.randomUUID();
            this.owner = owner;
            this.issuer = issuer;
            this.amount = amount;
            this.persistentChildToken = null;
            this.childProof = "I am a child";
        }

        // Default constructor required by hibernate.
        public PersistentGrandChildToken() {
            this.Id = UUID.randomUUID();
            this.owner = "";
            this.issuer = "";
            this.amount = 0;
            this.persistentChildToken = null;
            this.childProof = "I am a child";
        }

        public UUID getId() {
            return Id;
        }

        public String getOwner() {
            return owner;
        }

        public String getIssuer() {
            return issuer;
        }

        public int getAmount() {
            return amount;
        }

        public TokenSchemaV1.PersistentChildToken getPersistentChildToken() {
            return persistentChildToken;
        }
    }

}
```

---

Comment: Corda provides documentation on persistence as well https://docs.corda.net/api-persistence.html

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  Just one doubt.
Is it possible in corda to keep the table mapping in config file. Please refer 
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/quickstart/en-US/html/hibernate-gsg-tutorial-jpa.html for the configuration based entity mapping.