# How to specify schema for a particular JPA Repository?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

For JPA entity, we can specify the schema to be used for table creation via the @Table annotation as follows:
`@Table(name = "...", schema = "...")`

Consider a scenario where we create two tables with the same name but different schemas:
`@Table(name = "Table1", schema = "Schema1")` and
`@Table(name = "Table1", schema = "Schema2")`

Along with this we have defined the default schema for hibernate as `Schema1`

Now when we create a JPA repository and try to fetch the contents of the tables, only the contents of **Table1** in **Schema1** will be fetched as that is the schema defined as default.

My questions is: Is there a way to create two JPA Repositories for the two tables, so that one fetches data from `Schema1` while the other fetches from `Schema2`? If yes, how?

Note that both the schemas come from the same data source.

I haven't found a lot of resources which talk about this scenario; mainly the sources talk about defining schema for the table, or they talk about how to handle multiple datasources. Neither of which solve the problem at hand.

Comment: you can see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301399/jpa-using-multiple-database-schemas

Comment: Thanks @bardiadorry for the reference, however the solution on the link addresses a different problem and is not applicable in this case.

Comment: You have to create a new, separate persistence unit that has the default schema property set differently. There should be no problem with it using the same datasource as the first, though it is difficult to manage entities of the same class being used in multiple persistence units (reading from one then pushing to another can cause issues with change tracking, lazy loading etc). Persistence.xml is the easiest to define multiple named persistence units - dynamically in Spring is a bit more of a challenge - possible but not as straight forward.

Comment: I was considering this possibility, wanted to know if there is a simpler way to go about it, much like the @Table annotation, doesn't seem like there is one. Will probably go with an alternate design approach, thanks again.